# Is there a constructive version of the logic of Isabelle/HOL?

Tags: proof-verification, logic, foundations

Are there any constructive higher order logics? In particular, could one take the foundation of Isabelle/HOL remove excluded middle and choice and still have a powerful foundation of constructive math? It seems Isabelle's usage of structured proofs makes its syntax preferable to Coq but Isabelle/HOL, the by far largest Isabelle library, is entirely classical. What would the impediments be to making Isabelle/CHOL (Constructive HOL) in which all the classical theorems (T) could be rephrased as (excluded middle ==> choice ==> T)?

Comment: I could *imagine* having intuitionistically provable theorems in the Isabelle library depending on classically proven theorems just because the library was assumed to be "classical forever anyway". (No offense at Isabelle developers intended.)

Comment: I’m sure much of the library is not set up to easily constructivize that which can be constructivized, just because people just use whatever is easiest to prove something and that might not be the constructive(izable) proof. My question is more if there is a fundamental impediment to making Isabelle/HOL “constructive friendly”, so that things can be constructive if they want to be or classical if that makes sense, more like real math.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to "are there any constructive higher-order logics" is yes. [Martin-Löf type theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intuitionistic_type_theory) and its many descendants and variants are the examples that first come to mind.

However, you seem to be particularly interested in versions of simple type theory as implemented in Isabelle/HOL. In principle, the HOL logic as implemented in Isabelle is the same as that implemented in the other theorem provers in the HOL family (HOL IV, HOL Light, ProofPower, ...). John Harrison's HOL Light presents the logic in a way that clearly separates out the intuitionistic fragment (see his paper [HOL Light: an overview](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~jrh13/papers/hollight.html)). I suspect it would require some significant restructuring of Isabelle/HOL to adopt the HOL Light formulation. If that's something you'd like to happen, then I suggest you raise this on the Isabelle mailing list rather than here.

As a small aside: the axiom of choice implies the axiom of excluded middle in higher-order logic.

Comment: fascinating. may I ask - if Isabelle/HOL is based on ZFC under the hood: kicking out C, thus keeping ZF only wouldn't allow to have a HOL_ZF? or would Isabelle/HOL_ZF be less expressive than Isabelle/Martin-Löv-TT - because Matrin-Löv-TT is more expressive than ZF without C?

Comment: one more probably dumb question: with standard Isabelle/HOL, can it tell me whether it actually used C in some proof? IOW: whether the proof "is constructive" or implicitly requires me to believe in C?

Comment: @oberstet: for your first comment: Isabelle/HOL is based on simple type theory + the existence of an infinite type + AC. This is quite a lot weaker than ZFC from a set theorist's perspective, but in the applications HOL was designed for, the axiom of replacement and the oddities that you can get with untypable sets was not thought to be an issue (and isn't for an enormous range of applications including a great deal of pure mathematics. Your second comment really belongs on the Isabelle mailing list: my guess is that the answer is no, but I am no expert on Isabelle.

Comment: thanks a lot! also clearing up my misunderstanding that Isabelle/HOL would be based on ZFC, even though I don't fully understand what you say. fwiw, being more a computer guy these days, I just remembered the "C" in ZFC is rejected by constructivists. If it can't be constructed ("programmed") it doesn't exist;) So I should have probably asked: is Isabelle/HOL constructive, as in every existence proof implies a witness can be constructed? yeah, should ask this stuff on "proof assistants" SO. anyways, thanks a lot!

Comment: It's the "F" that adds the replacement axiom. So it would be closer to say that HOL is based on ZC (Zermelo set theory with choice). But it is a typed version of ZC and I believe that makes it strictly logically weaker than ZC (I would have to do some homework to confirm that belief, but I will if you would like me to.)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply! rgd "homework": please don't feel like that, the reason I don't fully understand is almost for sure the fact that I lack proper basics of set theory and logics. I did some lambda calculus etc but that is very long ago;) one misunderstanding of mine is probably: ZFC without C is constructive. Which is simply "confused" as "constructive" depends on the logic applied (skimmed over https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/set-theory-constructive/) - Constructive Zermelo-Fraenkel (CZF) and Intuitionistic Zermelo-Fraenkel (IZF) are constructive, classical logic ZF not.